# Rings of Prime Cardinality

Tags: ring-theory

Anyone know how to prove that if $R$ be a ring with identity with $|R|=p$, $p$ prime then $R$ is a field and that $R\cong \mathbb{Z}_p$ ?

Comment: **Hint** Consider the image of $\,\mathbb Z\,$ in $R$, i.e. the *characteristic* subring.

Comment: I applied a permutation on the title so it would make more sense (methinks).

Comment: @Asaf: An unfortunately consequence of the fact that language is not commutative...

Comment: Prove that for any ring, the elements of the form $1+1+\dots +1$ form a subring subring of $R$, isomorphic to a $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Since the order of a subring must divide the order of the ring, we know that this ring is in fact the whole ring $R$.

Comment: Lieven and as it follows that R is a field?

Comment: @Andres: Because you are proving that $R$ is isomorphic as a ring to $\mathbb{Z}_p$, and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a field. Are you confused about why if $R$ is isomorphic to a field then it's a field?

Answer (score 3):

The additive group generated by $1$ must be the whole ring (since it is a subgroup). Thus, every element is of the form $n\cdot 1$ for some $n\in\{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$. Moreover, $n$ is unique; the map that sends $n\cdot 1$ to $n\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ is now easily seen to be an isomorphism.

Comment: OK. In this case now as proof that for all $r\in R,\,\,\,r\neq 0$ exists $s\in R$ so that $rs=sr=1$?

Comment: @Andres:Well, you have an isomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}_p$, and the conclusion holds in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. What else could you possibly need? Or, if you *must* do things the hard way, if $a\neq 0$ then $aR=R$ (must be a subgroup, and is not $0$), so there exists $b\in R$ such that $ab=1$. And likewise, $Ra=R$, so there exists $c\in R$ such that $ca=1$. And $c = c1 = c(ab) = (ca)b = 1b = b$.