# Rings with the same additive law

Tags: ring-theory

Are there rings, on the same set, which have also the same additive law, but not the same multiplicative law ?

If the answer is yes, are there rings of cardinal $p$ (a prime) other than $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ ?

[Update] Here is an interesting link : [Rings of Prime Cardinality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160354/rings-of-prime-cardinality)

Comment: I'm leaving this as an answer because I can't comment. The answer to the second question is yes. Even more than what you ask, there are fields with cardinality $p$ other than $\Bbb Z_p$, (though they're all isomorphic).

Comment: Surely the question implied "up to isomorphism".

Comment: Are your rings unital?

Comment: I've just found a link : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160354/rings-of-prime-cardinality. It seems to say the contrary, no ?

Comment: You can answer for the two cases, but my favorite is the case "unital".

Comment: @Arnaud: a) There's no contradiction, since Sarango acknowledged that they're all isomorphic. b) That question assumes a multiplicative identity. c) You should add that link to the question.

Comment: In the non-unital case, there's a trivial multiplication that always yields $0$.

Comment: But what is the answer to the second question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The case of prime order $p$ having been already discussed in the answer by Sarango and the comments by OP and joriki, note that $\operatorname{GF}(p^{2})$ and $\mathbf{Z}_{p} \times \mathbf{Z}_{p}$ are unital rings with isomorphic additive structure, but one is a field, while the other is not an integral domain.